# Unreliable Google Awarness Weather API

Tags: android

I'm exploring the new Google Awareness API, more precisely the "get weather" one.

https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/snapshot-get-data#get_weather

Is several days that I'm testing, and I noticed two issues:

- int[] getConditions() always return a single element condition, instead of "a 2-element int array" like the documentation report;
- The condition is often very inaccurate.

Of course I tried with different locations around the world (mocking my location), comparing it with other weather services, and the results are the same.

Is that because they just release it? Or is it because I'm doing something wrong? This is my code:

```
Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(client)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<WeatherResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull WeatherResult weatherResult) {
                // weatherResult.getWeather().getConditions() contains the weather condition
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [public method summary](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/state/Weather#public-method-summary) says that getConditions() method of Weather (quoting verbatim) "Returns the current weather conditions as an array of values that best describe the current conditions."

In the link for [getConditions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/state/Weather.html#getConditions())(), the reference to 2-element array is just an example case for what would be returned if both conditions rainy and windy were applicable. In general it is an array that can contain one or more elements.

It is not clear from the question whether the issue reported is just for getConditions() or for other aspects of the weather such as temperature etc. If the other fields are accurate, it is less likely a problem with the update of the weather.